# Motor Controller with micro USB interface

Tags: mobile-robot, motor, wheeled-robot

I am a Robotics enthusiast and planning to make a small and simple four wheel car whose motors are supposed to be controlled by an Android device housed inside the car by means of the micro USB port of the device. The car has to move forward or backward only as directed by the signals from the Android device.

So my assumption is that there should be a circuit board which accepts the signals from the microUSB/USB of the Android device and controls the power to the electric DC motor. Also the power for the motor will be supplied from a battery pack inside the car.

Could anyone suggest me a cheap motor driver circuit which supports micro USB or USB? And where can I get the parts for this online? I did a lot research but very confused with the technical terms which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Xmindz, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: All the "motors controlled by Android" systems I've seen so far use (at least) 2 circuit boards. One board which acts as a USB host -- the [Arduino ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) or the Google ADK [Google ADK with Ben Heck](http://revision3.com/tbhs/androidadk); [Google ADK 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949616/google-adk-2012-where-to-buy). The other acts as a motor driver -- a ESC (which contains an Hbridge) or some other interface to an H bridge; there are [many motor drivers](http://opencircuits.com/Motor_driver).